# Flexbox ellipsize first child before second

Tags: css, flexbox, ellipsis

I'm have a flex-box container (`.search-bar`) with two text-containing divs (`.title`) inside.  I want the second child to take up all extra space and be the last to ellipsize as space becomes limited. i.e. the first child should ellipsize as necessary to keep the second child fully shown, and the second child should only ellipsize once the first child is no longer visible.

Demo:

```css
.search-bar {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 500px;
  background: white;
}

.title {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}

.title:last-of-type {
  flex: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.title + .title::before {
  content: '>';
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='search-bar'>
  <div class='title'>
  Doop Doop Doop Doop Doop Doop Doop
  </div>
  <div class='title'>
  Doge Doge Doge Doge Doge Doge Doge
  </div>
</div>
```

The `flex-shrink: 0` on the last-of-type title doesn't seem to do anything, and the last child is always the one that is ellipsized.

Is there a way to have the first title ellipsize before the second?

Here's a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6fs9gc00/

Comment: Is the second `.title` the last tag of its type in `.search-bar`? `:*-type` selectors apply to tags only,not class names.

Comment: Please include an MCVE, Andrew. It'll be easier to iterate through and help you with that.

Comment: @Shaggy, yeah the selector is being properly applied to the last `.title`.

Comment: Can't think of any setting/property that can "prioritize" shrinkage/ellipsis" in flexbox...in fact that the whole point of flexbox.

Comment: @TylerH added a jsFiddle with a basic example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to do it

```
.title {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.title.first {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
.title.last {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6nbzkkjg/4/

**Edit:** updated with @Andrew's modifications in comments

Comment: The only problem with that is that the second title won't ever ellipsize: https://jsfiddle.net/6nbzkkjg/3/

Comment: I was able to modify your example to get what I was looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/6nbzkkjg/4/

Comment: Doesn't look like that actually got updated.  If you update it with my changes, I'll mark your answer as accepted :)

Comment: Thanks. Added the link to your jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you can achieve this by adding `flex: 1;` to `.title {}`. If you change the width to 400px (for example), you can see that the second div will still truncate in an ellipsis, but the first div truncates first.

```css
.search-bar {
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 500px;
    background: #cfcfcf; /* Changed for visibility in Stack Snippet */
}

.title {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    flex: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
}

.title:last-of-type {
    flex: 1;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

.title + .title::before {
    content: '>';
    margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='search-bar'>
    <div class='title'>
        Doop Doop Doop Doop Doop Doop Doop
    </div>
    <div class='title'>
        Doge Doge Doge Doge Doge
    </div>
</div>
```

I removed `flex: 1;` and `align-content: center;` from `.search-bar {}` as they weren't doing anything.

Comment: This doesn't quite work how I'd like.  When setting `.search-bar` to have a width of 400px it ellipsizes both children at the same time.  I was able to come up with a solution based off of C14L's answer below: https://jsfiddle.net/6nbzkkjg/4/

Comment: @Andrew Ah, I see. I missed the last line of your question before the demo. Looks like you've got it figured out!

Answer (score 0):

My use case was a bit different because one of the children was an input, and they have a default width, so I could solve it using just `flex-shrink` and `max-width`. I didn't want that the left child used more than the 50% of the free space.

```
.title.first {
  max-width: 50%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```